# How to prove the quadratic transformation of hypergeometric function by using substitution?

Tags: integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

The fractional linear transformation of hypergeometric function can be proved by using substitution and integral expression of hypergeometric function.
$$
\begin{align}
 {}_2F_1\left( a,b;c;x \right) &= \frac{\Gamma \left( c \right)}{\Gamma \left( c-b \right) \Gamma \left( b \right)}\int_0^1{u^{b-1}\left( 1-u \right) ^{c-b-1}\left( 1-xu \right) ^{-a}du} \quad \small\text{, let $u=1-t$}
\\
&=\frac{\Gamma \left( c \right)}{\Gamma \left( c-b \right) \Gamma \left( b \right)}\int_0^1{\left( 1-t \right) ^{b-1}t^{c-b-1}\left( 1-x+xt \right) ^{-a}dt}
\\
&=\left( 1-x \right) ^{-a}\frac{\Gamma \left( c \right)}{\Gamma \left( c-b \right) \Gamma \left( b \right)}\int_0^1{\left( 1-t \right) ^{b-1}t^{c-b-1}\left( 1-\frac{x}{x-1}t \right) ^{-a}dt}
\\
&={\left( 1-x \right) ^{-a}} {}_2F_1\left( a,c-b;c;\frac{x}{x-1} \right) 
\end{align}$$

But I don't know how to prove the quadratic transformations by using the same method.

e.g.
$${\sideset{_2}{_1}F}\left( a,b;a+b+\frac{1}{2};4x\left( 1-x \right) \right) = {}_2F_1 \left( 2a,2b;a+b+\frac{1}{2};x \right) 
$$

Is it workable to prove this formula by using substitution?

Comment: The integral representation ${_2F_1}{\left(a,b;c;z\right)}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(b,c-b\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t^{b-1}\left(1-t\right)^{c-b-1}}{\left(1-zt\right)^{a}}$ only applies if $0<\Re{(b)}<\Re{(c)}$. The constraint this condition places on the parameters appearing in the quadratic transformation formula is then $0<b<a+\frac12$. So trying to prove the identity through integrals is going to force you to do extra casework you wouldn't have otherwise.